# Docker: How to volume map data from host to container (mongo) in using docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I am trying to volume map, data from host to container using docker-compose. I found this **docker-compose.yml** from [prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-server/local-prisma-setup-je3i/)

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '4466:4466'
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        managementApiSecret: mysecret42
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mongo
            uri: mongodb://prisma:prisma@mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: prisma
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - mongo:/var/lib/mongo
volumes: 
  mongo:
```

Problem Description:

1. `docker-compose up -d`,
2. add some data to mongodb
3. `docker-compose down`. the data gets removed.
4. Now, if I again `docker-compose up -d`. I have to add data again to mongodb

**How can I make data persistent (irrespective of container getting destroy)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked:

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: prisma
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db
volumes: 
  mongo:
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is not the behavior of docker.  There must be something in the prismagraph program that erases all the data every time it starts.

`docker compose down` requires a `-v` flag in order to remove named volumes.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

You can confirm this by doing:

`docker volume ls`

`docker volume inspect mongo`

*Update*: the location that mongo stores data is `/var/lib/mongodb`, not `/var/lib/mongo`

Change your docker-compose file and it should work.

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: prisma
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - mongo:/var/lib/mongodb
volumes: 
  mongo:
```

Comment: the following works for me 
```mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: prisma
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db
volumes: 
  mongo:```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me.

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: prisma
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/data:/data/db
  volumes:
    mongo:
```